# Is there way to compare lists in Python , similar to vlookup in excel

Tags: python

Python compare list1 with list2

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list2 = [2,3,4]
list_compare = ['not-found','found','found','found','not-found','not-found','not-found']
```

The length of "list1" and "list_compare" should be the same for writing it to a csv.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one-liner using list-comprehension

```
list1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list2= [2,3,4]

compared = ['found' if x in list2 else 'not-found' for x in list1]
print(compared) #['not-found', 'found', 'found', 'found', 'not-found', 'not-found', 'not-found']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas library to achieve this pretty easily.

```py
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2 = [2, 3, 4]

s1 = pd.Series(list1)
print(s1.isin(list2))
```

Output:

```py
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Here pandas returns generic `True/False` instead of found/not-found as suggested by you.

**NOTE**: Always try to use vectorized implementations, and library implementations, instead of writing your own code as those codes are generally pretty fast and accurate implementations.